# Prove that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=L>0$ then f is not bounded

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm trying to prove that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=L>0$ then f is not bounded. Tried to go from definitions and even state that f is not bounded and find contradiction, but got to dead end.

How may I show it?

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of the given limit: there's $A>0$ and if $x\ge A$ then $f'(x)\ge \frac L2$ and by the mean value theorem we have
$$f(x)-f(A)=f'(c)(x-A)\quad; \quad c\in (A,x)$$
hence
$$f(x)\ge \frac L2(x-A)+f(A)$$
so pass to the limit in the last inequality you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

There is an $x_0$ such that $f'(x)\geqslant L/2$ if $x\geqslant x_0$ (definition of a limit).
We thus have for $y\gt x_0$, 
$$f(y)-f(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^yf'(t)\mathrm dt\geqslant \frac L2(y-x_0).$$